# Google AppEngine DB Management best practice?

Tags: google-app-engine

Google app engine offer a data store (some kind of DB wrapper) to hold your data.
It does not supply an editor to this data store - only a viewer.

When developing a web application with other DB - MSSQL, MySql etc. - I change the DB structure in the development process many times.

In AE data store you should edit it's structure and data by using code - Java in my case.

Do you - AE developers - have any best practice to manage this DB updates and save them in some smart way for deployment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about "best practice", but I have a Servlet that I use during development which can upload and download all entity data as JSON.

I can then use a regular text editor to make changes or I use a hacked version of [JSONpad](https://github.com/Zerogiven/JSONpad) to edit data live in the system.

Since, I use JSON through out my application this works best for me.  One could also do the sample thing with XML and use any one of the many XML editors.

Also, I do use the low-level API for all my applications, so my data models tends to be fairly simple.

There are plenty of JSON/XML editors that could be adapter for your purposes, with a little bit of work.